# Включить отладку для нужного процесса из консоли

Tags: android, adb

Из эклипса это делается понятно как: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPp3W.png
Т.е. выделяю процесс, а потом кликаю на зеленом жучке. А как мне это же сделать, но из консоли (adb)?

UPD: небольшое уточнение. Мне не надо запускать процесс под отладкой. Мне нужно для уже запущенного процесса (не под отладкой) включить отладку.

UPD2:

```
adb shell am set-debug-app <пакет>
```

Он почему-то не работает. Точнее процесс останавливается, потом после перезапуска становится действительно под отладкой. Но мне надо отладка без перезапуска.

Comment: @flax, желательно указывать вопрос на который идет повтор.

Comment: Весело смотрю. Человек поставил минус, в комментарии не указал тему, потом вообще комментарий удалил. И мы ещё боремся за [зачеркнуть]SO[/зачеркнуть] звание дома высокой культуры?

Comment: @Schumi, я немного превысил полномочия указав автора тревоги.  
Это сделано, чтобы он получил уведомление.  
Автора тревоги я взял из рассылки, а не удаленного комментария.

Comment: Обновил первый пост, может непонятно...

Comment: Ещё изменил первый пост